# How to put 3 elements in one row in a parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have put 3 div elements in another div element like this:

```html
<div id="mom">
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
    <div class="baby"></div>
</div>
```

When resize my browser so the parent's width changes, something happens: "3 element near together."

I can not set margin left and right auto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want a fix margin but dynamic width? That takes a little more markup, unless you're willing to drop support for IE9 and below by using flexbox.

The thing is, you can't split 100% into percentages and fix values (dynamic width, fix margin) just like that. (there are ways using `calc()` .. but if you're going to use calc, you could also use flexboxes instead.

Note: The child elements aren't exactly the same width. There won't be a (non-flexbox, non-calc) way to achieve this.

Here's an example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M48NW/)) with a little more markup, but IE8 and 9 support.

HTML:

```
<div class="mom">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="childinner">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="childinner">Amet laborum cupiditate.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="childinner">Ratione maxime et!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mom {
    width: 100%; /* Try setting this to 400px or something */
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.child {
    display: table-cell;
}
.childinner {
    margin-left: 25px;
    /* Decorative .. */
    background-color: #cccccc;
    min-height: 40px;
}
.child:first-child .childinner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/3F5WQ/4/

Only use `float:left;` and use `percentage` for width.

```
#mom{
    width: 100%;        
}

.baby{ 
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 26.67%; 
    margin-left: 5% ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to mention `display: table;` on your parent `div` and `display: table-cell;` on your child `div`. i've posted a sample code on jsfiddle..

```
   #mom
    {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .baby
    {
        display: table-cell;
        color: red;
        background: #333333;
    }
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/8/)

Comment: No explanation? Also, mom needs `width: 100%`. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwshE/6/)

Comment: @MildlyInteresting : i'm trying to update my fiddle.. so it takes time to update the answer with explanation

Comment: guys I want 3 child div on same line and they had margin left and right = 20px with together

Comment: @mamal10 setting margin to 20px is quite different from setting margin to auto. you have to decide.

Comment: my friend I want this 3 child elements had margin-right & margin-left with together for example 20px. your code is right but haven't any distance between 3 elements!!!

Answer (score 1):

change `<div class="mom">` to `<div class="d-flex">` and thats it. No need to add classes to child div for positions purposes